Does malloc consider TLB hits?
I recently tried to examine how malloc() and free() populate the address space with differently sized chunks of memory on my system. It is a debian linux with the glibc malloc implementation and 4 GB of RAM.
And as described in Malloc Internals, I noticed how the program tries to populate recently freed chunks of similar size. I think there is a tendency to keep chunks that are the size of a page or larger free. This would make sense in case malloc() wants to return a free page to the operating system. That also corresponds with the malloc-algorithm, as it will go for smaller chunks and coalesced space first, if I read it correctly.
At the end though, the address space seemed somewhat polluted (fragmented) anyway. This might be because of my custom weird allocation.
Now my question is: Does malloc() consider the TLB of the system it is running on? If i recall correctly staying compact is key to keep the TLB hits up. This has to be even more important on smaller systems (because the TLB will be smaller too i guess).

Which implementation of malloc ?

Which operating system?

I think there's little malloc could do to optimize TLB use. There's generally so much code executed between malloc and free calls that it's not very likely that the block being freed is still in the TLB. The heuristics you mentioned are more coarsely grained and have a better chance of hitting memory that hasn't been paged out yet.

(a) There are numerous malloc implementations. (b) malloc has no information about when the program will use the memory it is requesting. For example, it is entirely normal to request a buffer at one point in the program and not use it until later. Or multiple nodes of same complicated data structure might be allocated, used briefly during initial setup, and then not used for a long time. So malloc has nearly zero ability to affect any TLB or cache timing.

I updated the question with OS and specified the version of malloc.

If you're worried about whether using memory from malloc() will cause a TLB miss, you shouldn't be using new memory from a fresh call to malloc().
